# PHP Socket is connected but does not read data

Tags: php

```
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        socket_set_option($socket,SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec"=>2, "usec"=>0));
        $result = socket_connect($socket, $this->ip, $this->port);

        if($result <= 0) {
            echo "connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) \n";
        }
            $data = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x54\x53\x6F\x75\x72\x63\x65\x20\x45\x6E\x67\x69\x6E\x65\x20\x51\x75\x65\x72\x79\x00";
            socket_write($socket, $data, strlen($data));

                $out = socket_read($socket, 4096);
                socket_close($socket);
                if($out == null ){
                    echo 'data null';
                }
                else {
                    $queryData = explode("\x00", substr($out, 6), 5);
                    $server['ip'] = $this->ip;
                    $server['port'] = $this->port;
                    $server['name'] = $queryData[0];
                    $server['map'] = $queryData[1];
                    $server['game'] = $queryData[2];
                    $server['description'] = $queryData[3];
                    $packet = $queryData[4];
                    //$app_id = array_pop(unpack("S", substr($packet, 0, 2)));
                    $server['players'] = ord(substr($packet, 2, 1));
                    $server['playersmax'] = ord(substr($packet, 3, 1));
                    $server['bots'] = ord(substr($packet, 4, 1));
                    $server['dedicated'] = substr($packet, 5, 1);
                    $server['os'] = substr($packet, 6, 1);
                    $server['password'] = ord(substr($packet, 7, 1));
                    $server['vac'] = ord(substr($packet, 8, 1));
                    $this->info = $server;
                           echo "<pre>";
                            print_r($queryData);
                            echo "</pre>";
                }
        //error_reporting($oldErrorReporting);
```

This code work on my old server (centos + php5 + apache2);
and after transfer to another server (ubuntu + php5 + apache2), it stopped working.

When The problem is not to set up php (it is on the socket support), but the fact that he simply does not receive a request, although no connection error, he betrays.
Among the possible reasons for thinking that the problem of accessing the service socket with external ip, but I did not know how to fix it.
Thanks in advance for your answers!